# Flow to create multiple tasks for different queue

Tags: visual-workflow, tasks, bulkification, queue

**Use Case**
When an Opportunity Stage is changed to "Approved" , create multiple Tasks and assign to different Queues -

1. Create Task for  'Customer Management Queue'
2. Create Task for one or both of the following queues based on value in Main_Company__c field

   IF Opportunity. Main_Company__c = "KML"  create Task and assign to  'KML Queue'

   IF Opportunity. MainCompany = "Mead"   create Task for 'Mead Queue'

   IF Opportunity. MainCompany = "Mead"; "KLM" create Task for 'Mead Queue' and another task for
   KLM team
3. Create Task for 'Legal Queue
   After the Legal Team Closes this Task, create another Task for 'Maintenence Queue'

**My Approach**

1. Create Flow on Object Opportunity
2. Condition   ischanged: StageName AND StageName = "Approved"
3. Create resources (variable, text)  for each of the Queue Developer Name
4. Get  each of the Queue so that WhoID is avaiable as groupID
5. Create New Records. Object =  Task.

**Here is where I am struggling**

If all the Tasks are created at the same time, how should I structure the flow ?

Should I create a another flow to create new task after Legal Queue Completes the task ?

**Here is the screen shot of my attempt**

[image]

[image]

Comment: _After the Legal Team Closes this Task, create another Task for 'Maintenance Queue'_ needs to be a separate flow (not a subflow) triggered on the Task object.

Comment: Thanks i will create another flow for 'Maintenance task'.  Do you think based on my use case, i am creating the flow correctly?

Comment: Yes, you're on the right track.